# Failed to lazily initialize a collection and Fail-safe cleanup

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-initialization

While trying to fetch results from a query where I have `fetchJoin` in all sets that I am interested, some times it works but sometimes no results are being returned and I get these exceptions:

> HHH000327: Error performing load command :
>    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
>    HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) :
>    org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@67a3d5f3
>    HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [420] entries

Comment: This doesn't seem at all relevant to jQuery. I've removed the tag for you

Comment: set your query method in one transaction